# Having difficulties with simple ajax implementation with jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I'm trying to implement simple ajax by using jquery in mvc. I'm just trying to load some contents from another page in the current page. My code is looks like this:

```
<div>
    <ul id="biographies">
    <li> <a href="Ajax">Ajax</a></li>
    <li> <a href="Index">Index</a>  </li>

    </ul>    

    <div id="biography">
      The ajax content will appear here...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#biographies html.ActionLink').click(function (e) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#biography').load(url);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

But having some problem as follows:

1. When I keep the ajax.cshtml file in Home folder under view, its showing content not found, I need to know how to link internal resource in mvc using simple anchor tag not html.actionlink method.
2. When I keep the ajax.cshtml file in the root directory, it just move to that page rather than loading the contents in first page,which is expected.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move to that page, because you are loading the page, not making async call to load the contents. I would suggest you make pure ajax call using $.ajax check this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax  And in your controller action you may use JsonResult that returns the data in Json format. in asp.net mvc you may cast your data to json using Json('your data').

Answer (score 0):

Replace

$('#biographies html.ActionLink')

with

**$('#biographies a')**

Comment: From your code i understand you are taking href attribute from anchor tag. The selector needs to be list of anchor tags not #biographies.  So you need to get all the anchor tags under #biographies , i.e $('#biographies a')

Comment: Did it, but not working, the first problem is its showing server error, resource can not be found found! Is there any problem with the hyperlink code? my view files are kept as usual e.i. under view>home>ajax.

Comment: Replace <li> <a href="Ajax">Ajax</a></li>
 to <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ajax", "Ajax", "Home")</li>. This is razor syntax. If you use web form view engine follow <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Ajax", "Ajax", "Home")%></li>